# Content-Security-Policy blocks Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, content-security-policy

I am serving a HTML page in my node.js server with express.public() function.

and i added this into my html page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

And Chrome gaves me a Content-Security-Policy to me.

I used this middlewares in my Node index.js

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("./public"));
```

My application headers:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

How can i add this script without any SecurityPolicy

**SOLVED**

I remove "Helmet" from my project. Helmet is blocking the all cdn and scripts other then absolute domain.

Comment: Could you include the security policy that is sent by the server, you can grab this via the browser's developer tools (F12), then look for the request headers of the main request

Comment: I added it u can check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Content Security Policy is set in the html file being served or by the software serving the html (e.g Nginx, Apache).

At the moment you have: default-src 'self', this means you are telling the browser that it is only able to make requests to its own domain.

You need to add https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js to this list of domains it can access.

That would be something like:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js; base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

So default-src: self sets the default to restrict requests to only your own domain.

script-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js overrides this and says specifically for scripts restricts request to only your domain and that url.

This has lots of details and examples:
https://content-security-policy.com

Comment: In your first sentence you say the CSP is set in the index.html. This makes no sense, one cannot influence response headers from within a html document. A webserver can do this.

Comment: I believe there are two methods for setting the content security policy. One is embedding a meta tag directly into the html of the page you are serving, the second is getting the server (for example Apache, Nginx) to set it. See https://blog.sucuri.net/2018/04/content-security-policy.html, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what silent-tiger said, I think you should first find out which middleware is responsible for adding this content  policy. Do this by disabling all middleware (except express static) and then add the other middlewares one by one until you see the Content Secutity Policy headers again.

If you found which middleware is responsible, then you know which middleware you should configure.